# Consulta SQL sem elemento repetido

Tags: sql

Tenho essa consulta em sql

```
SELECT 
    "Certificates"."Email", 
    "Organizations"."CommonName", 
    "Certificates"."Id", 
    "Certificates"."OrganizationId"
FROM
    "Certificates"
INNER JOIN 
    "Organizations" ON "Organizations"."Id" = "Certificates"."OrganizationId"
ORDER BY 
    "Email"
LIMIT 
     15
OFFSET 
     0
```

Porém ela me retorna todos os certificados, sendo que há certificados com emails repetidos, gostaria que fosse apenas emails únicos, tentei usar DISTINCT depois do SELECT, mas ele continua retornado a mesma coisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comportamento da sua query está correto. É provável que o `Id` da sua tabela não se repita, portanto, retorna os dados sem agrupamento mesmo com `Distinct`.

Para que os resultados retornem de forma agrupada, utilize a query abaixo.

```
SELECT     
    "Certificates"."Email", 
    "Organizations"."CommonName", 
     MAX("Certificates"."Id"), 
    "Certificates"."OrganizationId"
FROM
    "Certificates"
INNER JOIN 
    "Organizations" ON "Organizations"."Id" = "Certificates"."OrganizationId"
GROUP BY
   "Certificates"."Email", 
    "Organizations"."CommonName",
    "Certificates"."OrganizationId"
ORDER BY 
    "Email"
LIMIT 
     15
```

Comment: De fato com essa consulta ele retorna sem emails repetidos, mas eu fico sem o Id, e na minha aplicação eu vou usar o Id também.

Comment: E se possível na hora de comparar 2 emails diferentes, ele pegar o que tem o Id maior

Comment: Sim, atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Sensacional, obrigado pela ajuda